# Clicking email content should call a python fucntion?

Tags: python, email, onclick, smtplib

I am working on an assignment in which I have to the send an email to the customer and if he clicks the accept link in the email, call the python function that completes the desired functionality and adds it to the database.

My question is how can we call a function from the email text.

The email might be like this:-
    Kindly click the accept link to complete the action
    [ACCEPT](http://ACCEPT)

Demo email code:

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

def success_email():
    sender = 'abhishek_talwar@xyz.com'
    recipients = 'GANA_PANGO@xyz.com'
    CC = 'abhishek_talwar@xyz.com'
    subject = "Load Balance Request Completed"
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = recipients
    msg['CC'] = CC
    # Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
    text = 'Hi this is a test mail'
    # Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
    part1 = MIMEText(text.encode('utf-8'), 'html')
    # Attach parts into message container.
    msg.attach(part1)
    s = smtplib.SMTP('mail1.xyz.com')
    x =s.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
    print x
    action = 'Success email sent for'
    print action


    success_email()
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a web project which it seems to be, you **may need to specify a url and bind it to a controller function**. whenever the user clicks the accept button in the email (which is in fact an html) , he will be redirected to the specified url and the corresponding controller function will be called. you may then need to save whatever you want in the database in the controller function. Please note that the controller function for "sending an email" and "capturing the user click" must be different.